# How can I make a textarea align horizontally with a label in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5

EDIT: The issue was due to a single typo which was pointed out to me in a comment and corrected.

I am trying to make a pretty basic contact form using Bootstrap 5. I want the labels to line up horizontally with their associated inputs on wider screens, and vertically on mobile/narrower screens (in other words, to look and behave like the "Horizontal Form" example given [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/), whose code I am using as a guide). Everything works as desired with the `<input>`s and `<select>`s in my form, but the one `<textarea>` always appears below its label instead of to the right of it.

My code is more or less as follows:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="mx-auto col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
<form action="order-form.php">
    <div class="row mb-2"> <!-- mb-3 class = -->
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Your email:</label> <!-- col-sm-2 = ; col-form-label = ; -->
        <div class="col-sm-6"> <!--  -->
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your email" style="width: 350px"> <!-- form-control = -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Your name and title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your name and title:" style="width: 350px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="type" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Some choice:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <select name="type" class="form-control" id="type" style="width: 350px">
                <option value="choice1" selected>Choice 1</option>
                <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
                <option value="choice3">Choice 3</option>
                <option value="choice4">Something else</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-mb-2">
        <label for="instructions" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Instructions:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <textarea type="text" rows="2" name="instructions" class="form-control" id="instructions" placeholder="Special requests or instructions" style="width: 350px"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's what the form looks like so far on a wide screen – the textarea is below its label, but I want it to be to the right of it, and only appear below it on narrower screens.

[image]

I have tried adjusting column widths and reducing the number of rows in the textarea to no avail, and I have not been able to find current bootstrap documentation addressing textarea inputs in horizontal forms. How do I fix this?

Comment: <div class="row-mb-2"> typo here i think ?

Comment: @MarekRand Thanks for catching that! Problem solved.